# xml layout in android that supports different screen sizes

Tags: android-layout

how should we set the xml layout in android that supports different screen sizes.
I tried using wrap content and match parent but its not working properly. Please guide me for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

The comment about, Supporting Multiple Screens is defiantly a good starting place! By default your xml does support different screen sizes.

`Although the system performs scaling and resizing to make your application work on different screens, you should make the effort to optimize your application for different screen sizes and densities. In doing so, you maximize the user experience for all devices and your users believe that your application was actually designed for their devices—rather than simply stretched to fit the screen on their devices.`

However, like it says you need to optimize it. This refers to images or a completely different xml per screen size/orientation. Does this help any?

If you need something a little more specific to your situation you'll need to provide more information.

Comment: so how should the xml layout be designed for different screen sizes?can you please guide me in detail..

Comment: It really just depends on what your doing, here's some more conceptional things in the doc's: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/11/designing-for-tablets-were-here-to-help.html and here is a tutorial on fragments and how to use them with and without tablets: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html

Comment: i have images of four sizes ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi nd i have put all these images in the respective drawable folders and even i have set the width and height of the imageview to wrap_content but still the image doesnt look proper on all screen sizes.Please help me out for this.Thankyou.

Comment: Can you post them XML and 1 image with all the variations?

Comment: Also did you use this to create the sizes: http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

Comment: Awesome, Accept the answer if it was enough help.